# How to detect screen resolution in qt?

Tags: c++, linux, qt, framebuffer

I set resolution of frame buffer in Intel platform using ioctl methods of Linux kernel. I able to set this resolution successfully (verify with again get this parameters) but didn't get in qt. When I check desktop geometry it was get which I set on boot (1920*1024) and also not getting resizeevent(). Can somebody say where am lacking .... ?

Comment: I also connect resize signal but it also won't work.  connect(QApplication::desktop(), SIGNAL(resized(int)), this, SLOT(resized(int)));

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
QDesktopWidget widget;
QRect mainScreenSize = widget.availableGeometry(widget.primaryScreen());
```

Comment: I also tried this but not get any updation of geomatry

Comment: It might be that the Qt platform plugin you're using didn't notice that the resolution changed. Which platform plugin, and which Qt version? Is it the latest, and have you checked the Qt bug tracker for bugs?